# Aurelia how to do async work in attached method of custom component

Tags: asynchronous, aurelia

This seems like a basic flow, but I am unable to find examples.

I have this custom component that loads a list of items from a backend service.
I tried writing this async code below, but I get 'Unexpected token' error in the browser at **let**.

```js
import {customElement, bindable, inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {ItemsService} from 'Services/ItemsService';

@customElement('itemslist')
export class ItemsList {

    static inject() { return [Element, ItemsService]; }

    constructor(element, itemsService) {
        this.element = element;
        this.itemsService = itemsService;
    }

    async attached() {
        let this.items = await this.itemsService.getItemList();
    }
}
```

How should I do async work to load items and set it on my View-Model **items** property?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`let` keyword is used to declare local variables, you can't use it before `this`. Just remove `let`. Declare your `items` property in constructor or with ES7 syntax.

Babel's `async/await` transformer must be enabled- Change [this](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/blob/1.0.0-beta.1.0.1/config.js#L4-L9):

**config.js**

```
  "babelOptions": {
    "optional": [
      "es7.decorators",
      "es7.classProperties"
    ]
  },
```

To this:

```
  "babelOptions": {
    "optional": [
      "es7.decorators",
      "es7.classProperties",
      "es7.asyncFunctions"
    ]
  },
```

Or this:

```js
  "babelOptions": {
    "stage": 0
    "optional": ["runtime"]
  },
```